# Firebase AppCheck v8 in React: 400 error "Invalid App ID: \"undefined\"."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have been trying to implement appCheck on my Firebase project. I followed the Firebase docs and checked a bunch of StackOverflow articles, but can't seem to get it to work properly. I'm getting a "400: Bad Request" error when trying to use appCheck and it's telling me my App ID is invalid ("undefined"). The app works fine without appCheck. I have only implemented/tested this on localhost (haven't tried deploying), and I did setup the debug token as well.

error seen when adding appCheck

[image: 1]

What I've done so far:

1. Created a new reCaptcha v3 site with keys
2. Added/registered the secret key in Firebase
3. Imported app-check library
4. Initialized & activated appCheck with reCaptcha key
5. Added self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true; to index.html
6. Added the debug token to Firebase

any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```js
import { firebase } from "@firebase/app";
import 'firebase/auth';
import "@firebase/auth";
import "@firebase/storage";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/app-check";

const firebaseKey = process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY;
const firebaseProjectId = process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID;
const firebaseAuthDomain = process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN;
const firebaseStorageBucket = process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET;
const recaptchaKey = process.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHA_KEY;

const options = {
  apiKey: firebaseKey,
  authDomain: firebaseAuthDomain,
  projectId: firebaseProjectId,
  storageBucket: firebaseStorageBucket,
};

const client = firebase.initializeApp(options);

const appCheck = firebase.appCheck(client);
appCheck.activate(recaptchaKey, true);

export default client;
export { firebase };
```

And this is what I have in my index.html file:

```html
<body>
    <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
    <script>
      if (window.location.hostname === "localhost")
        self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
    </script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a typo when defining appId in my firebase config object.

I see that you're missing the appId property in yours. Adding it should fix this error.

```
const options = {
  apiKey: firebaseKey,
  authDomain: firebaseAuthDomain,
  projectId: firebaseProjectId,
  storageBucket: firebaseStorageBucket,
  appId: 'your app id from firebase console'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are missing appId in your config:

```
const options = {
  apiKey: firebaseKey,
  authDomain: firebaseAuthDomain,
  projectId: firebaseProjectId,
  storageBucket: firebaseStorageBucket,
  appId: "YOU_ARE_MISSING_THIS"
};
```

to get the appId, go to your firebase console, click to the cog next to Project Overview -> Project Settings -> select the app and you will see the appId

[image]